# rails - Search form in tags and title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, acts-as-taggable-on

I have an application where I have two models: `debates` and `challenges`.

Every model has a title, and I use `acts_as_taggable` on both.

I have a search form where I can search on every tags:

**view**

```
<%= form_tag ("/search_results"), :method => "get", :id=>"search-form" do %>

  <%= text_field_tag ("search") , nil, :id=>"search-text",
    :onblur=>"if(this.value=='')this.setAttribute('class', 'search_input');",
    :onfocus=>"this.setAttribute('class', 'search_input_clear');",
    placeholder: "Chercher un débat"
 %>
<% end %>
```

and on **my controller**:

```
def search_results
 @challenges = Challenge.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}")
 @debates = Debate.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}")
 @lists =   @debates + @challenges
end
```

The question is, how can I combine search on tags and on titles in the same search tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show results with matching title and tagged as well, than you can something like this:

```
def search_results
 @tag_challenges = Challenge.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}")
 @title_search = Challange.where(:title => params[:search])
 @challenges =   @tag_challenges +  @title_search

 @tag_debates = Debate.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}")
 @title_debates = Debate.where(:title => params[:search]) 
 @debates = @tag_debates + @title_debates 
 @lists =   @debates + @challenges
end
```

You only have to find the unique records of these. And I think you are able to do that.

**Edit**

Not a problem, you can write SQL like queries here as well:

```
@title_search = Challange.where("title LIKE %#{params[:search]}%")

@title_debates = Debate.where("title LIKE %#{params[:search]}%")
```

Now it will search for every text in your title.

Thanks

Comment: Great! It works If I enter the whole title in the search box, but what if I only search for one word of the title ? Sorry I don't have enough credits to vote up